# not seeing mysql general logs

Tags: mysql, linux, logging

`SELECT @@GLOBAL.general_log_file` says that the general log is at /var/lib/mysql/dev.log. So I do `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON'` to make it so the general log is on, run a query, and check /var/lib/mysql via the command line and...  there is no dev.log file present. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to create the file myself before mysql can write to it?

The /var/lib/mysql directory is owned by user mysql and the bin log files are present in it and it appears that they're actively being written to.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What `SELECT @@GLOBAL.log_output` shows?

Comment: Try `FLUSH LOGS` as a last resort.